# Best plant to provide barrier hedge

Tags: hedge, screening

I need a good hedge plant that can act as a barrier between back and side garden. The area can get a lot of wind and gets late sun. At present there is 
ivy that has been there for years over a pergola wall.

I want to get rid of ivy but need to replace with something else, easy to keep but that would provide some protection when grown. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What part of the world are you in? You mention a pergola - does that mean you want something that will climb up it,, or just stand in front of it?

Comment: It might seem counter-intuitive, but to make a good wind barrier you don't want something "solid" that blocks the wind, forces it over the top of the hedge, and then creates a huge eddy and turbulence on the down-wind side, but something that lets *some* of the wind through. Not knowing where in the world you are, it's hard to make any specific suggestions.

Comment: I've seen lilac rows used to great effect for that purpose.

Comment: sun chokes work well, and provide a nice food crop in the late fall when the first frost comes.

Comment: Tallhedge buckthorn